# Getting first item in the PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Need help to loop through this. I want to add a different styling to my first item in the loop.

I have tried to use [How to determine the first and last iteration in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop) and [PHP - Grab the first element using a foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957768/php-grab-the-first-element-using-a-foreach) somehow it is not wroking out. The two blocks above also seem to share issues of speed on applying code

Look at the comments in the code to better understand my question.

```
  <?php 
                        $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => true ));

                        foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat => $item ) {
                            $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                            $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog' );
                            $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );  ?>

                            <!-- if first item echo
                            <div class="col-md-8 fig-hold">
                                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <div class="figure">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" />
                                        <div class="figureName"><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>


                            else -->                
                            <div class="col-md-4 fig-hold">
                                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <div class="figure">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" />
                                        <div class="figureName"><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                    <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: omukiguy, see my answer.

Comment: @ionut I am trying it out but so far. It's not displaying the results

Comment: Well, that's another problem. You should post another question about that. My code should work on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter, and based on that, add a class to the first element, and you can now style that class with `CSS`:

```html
<?php
$prod_categories = get_terms('product_cat', array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true
));
$count = 0;
$class = '';
foreach ($prod_categories as $prod_cat => $item) {
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) {
        $class = 'extra_class';
    }else{
        $class = '';
    }
    $cat_thumb_id     = get_woocommerce_term_meta($prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog');
    $term_link        = get_term_link($prod_cat, 'product_cat');
?>             
          <div class="col-md-4 fig-hold <?php echo $class; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                   <div class="figure">
                      <img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" />
                      <div class="figureName"><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?></div>
                   </div>
                 </a>
          </div>

<?php
} wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. I tweaked it a bit to suit my need.

Comment: I moved the loop after the variables and executed the classes (Bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code. Thanks @ionut

```
<?php 
    $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', 
                                 array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => true ));

    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) {
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog' );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' ); 

    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) {  $class = 'col-md-8'; } else{ $class = 'col-md-4'; }
     ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?> fig-hold">
        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <div class="figure">
                <img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" />
                <div class="figureName"><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```